# What is the best way of integrating TeamCity and Crashlytics?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, crashlytics

We are developing mobile apps (both Android and iOS) and started to build our apps with TeamCity. The problem is how to upload our builds made by TeamCity to the Crashlytics? How do you solve this problem?

Comment: I am not aware of Crashlytics requirement. What exactly do you need to upload?

Comment: @NikitaSkvortsov ipa for iOS builds and apk for Android builds.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of existing TeamCity of Crashlytics plugins for integration.
The simpliest workaround would be adding a `Command Line Runner` build step with a call to `curl` that will upload rerquired files.

Answer (score 0):

For iOS you can use fastlane and trigger the uploading through the teamcity.
Fastlane has plugins for crashlytics.

For android you can write a custom script to upload the artifact (apk) to crashlytics. 
We are using Hockey app and doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a little late but below gradle command will upload you apk to crashlytics beta

```
./gradlew crashlyticsUploadDistributionRelease
```

For details, you can have a look at Crashlytics [Beta distribution](https://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/388925-beta-distributions-with-gradle) docs.